# Force apache to server different directories on different ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, port, directory

For example, say I have my htdocs in:

```
~/public_html
```

and those documents are being served on port 80.  Is there any way to make apache server documents in:

```
~/public_html/something
```

on a different port?  Or does that require a separate instance of apache?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It requires a different [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

Just set up two virtual hosts that listen on different ports, let the second have a different document root and forbid access to 'something' within the first.

Comment: +1 correct - you just need a new vhost with a different docroot

Comment: Thanks!  I'd vote up, but need 15 reputation before I can.

Comment: 2013 comment!!!

Answer (score 14):

Sure, first you'll have to set apache to listen on two ports. So in your httpd.conf set

Listen 80

Listen 8080

Then create two vhost configurations (/etc/apache/sites-enabled/000-default). The first can be *:80 and the second *:8080. Set the respective DocumentRoots.

<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot ~/public_html

Blah Blah....

</VirtualHost>

and...

<VirtualHost *:8080>

DocumentRoot ~/public_html/something

Blah Blah....

</VirtualHost>

Comment: Wow, you took Manni's answer a step further.  Thanks for the example config stuff, it's very helpful.  Sorry I can't upvote, but I will when I get 15 reputation!